# Connecting to a firebird superserver on windows using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, firebird

I am trying to connect to a firebird super server.I have the fdb package installed.

I am trying

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine ('localhost:c:\fdbb\school.fdb')
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\engine\__init__.py", line 332, in creat
e_engine
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 48, in crea
te
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\engine\url.py", line 154, in make_url
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\sqlalchemy\engine\url.py", line 196, in _parse_rfc
1738_args
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string 'localhost
:c:♀dbb\school.fdb'
```

Am i doing this right?.

Comment: At the last line of the error, drive separator seems to be corrupted, instead of "\" there is `♀` - is this is the actual error message?

Comment: Yes that is the actual error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it this way

```
import sqlalchemy
import fdb
```

> engine =
>   create_engine('firebird+fdb://sysdba:masterkey@localhost:3050/c:/fdbb/school.fdb')